# why do I have no option for luxcore API

Tags: rendering, add-on, properties

I downloaded luxrender, but every time I try to render anything an error comes up that viewpoint rendering is only available when luxcore API is selected. I wanted to change the luxrender API from classic to Luxcore API but There's no option for that. What should I do? Yes my system does not support openCL. So I downloaded luxrender no openCL from the luxrender site, during the installation when it was extracting Luxblend it starts to give error message through out the rest of the installation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Luxrender 1.6 fine on both my Linux machine and the Windows one with LuxCore API. However, it can be tricky to set it up correctly. I can imagine two scenarios where the LuxCore API won't show up:

1. You have installed Luxrender correctly, but forgot to update the LuxBlend plugin. Remember that the Luxrender installer does not do this automatically for you. The Luxrender version and LuxBlend plugin really need to be of the same installer, they break compatibility very quickly.
2. You are trying to use the Luxrender OpenCL installer, but your system doesn't support it (that was the issue on my linux machine)

If it is 1., then you can open up Blender, go to User Preferences -> Addons, find the LuxRender plugin, and remove it completely from your system. Then, Save your User Prefs, quit Blender and restart. This ensures that when you install the new version, the Python cache will for sure be regenerated. Now install the Plugin, you can find it in the Programs folder where you installed Luxrender to. So again, User Preferences, Addons, 'Install from File', and point to *your folder*/Luxrender/LuxBlend.zip. It should look like this on Windows:

[image]

You should now see the addon and be able to activate it. Set the Path to your Luxrender installation correctly, Save User settings, and restart. Note from the screenshot the plugin version:

[image: LuxBlend plugin]

With the newest plugins, they also added a 'Update LuxBlend' button. At the moment I recommend using it, because then the 'Opactiy' option for area lights will show up, but that's a topic you can find on the LuxRender forum.

In case of 2.: Uninstall Luxrender, Download the non-open-cl package, and try that.

[image: no openCL Luxrender]

Comment: xblend it starts to give error message through out the rest of the installation.

Comment: could you please be more specific? what error is thrown? at what part of the installation? did you make sure to uninstall the old Plugin and restart Blender? A few more details might help.

Comment: I have not uninstalled the previous version I will try that

Comment: Hi John, I had the same issue again on another machine here at work. Again, following the procedure described in Step 1 fixed it, Luxrender is running. I've updated my answer to show you which file to pick when reinstalling the LuxRender addon. Did you have a chance to try it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Responses to the luxrender [1.6RC1](http://www.luxrender.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=12753) and [1.6](http://www.luxrender.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=12885) release notes mention some incompatibility with blender 2.77

It sounds like the luxrender releases are still built using python 3.4 while blender 2.77 uses python 3.5

Current options would appear to be using blender 2.76 or building your own copy of luxrender that links to python 3.5